# `str.find` works, but `re.finditer` does not find a match

Tags: python, regex

I have 2 strings and I want to find all locations of one string within another. String.find works but not regex.

sub: (dont want to) call in

str1: i cant (dont want to) call in

```
 str1.find(sub) returns 7 but 
   [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(sub,str1)] returns empty list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are metacharacters in regex (used to capture groups), so you'll need to escape them if they are to be treated literally:

```
sub = '\(dont want to\) call in'
```

Alternatively, you may use `re.escape`, which automatically escapes the metacharacters for you:

```
re.finditer(re.escape('(dont want to) call in'), str1)
```